# SharePoint 2010 Pull Library Preview Text

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have WCF service that is pulling a list of PDF files from SharePoint 2010. When I use the search bar on SharePoint to search for files, I get a list of items which include the Title, Authors, etc etc. I also get a small text preview of what's actually in the file as shown below:
[image]

How can I pull that text preview into my WCF service? The DataContext in my service that I'm using to get the list data doesn't contain it. Is there some field that needs to be exposed on SharePoint?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from SharePoint?  Are you using the query web service (/_vti_bin/search.asmx) or the KeywordQuery class (Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.KeywordQuery) or some other method?

Comment: My service consumes /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx from SharePoint.

Comment: The file contents are only going to be available if you use the Search web service instead of the Lists one.  The Search services uses the search indexed copy of the content which includes the full text (where the preview is from).  If you're using SP 2010, you can use the Query method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcsearch.queryservice.query(v=office.14).aspx